# Doing a google search before UIWebView is shown

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

Is it possible to present www.Google.com in a webview with some text already searched? For example, can I search for Mcdonalds and have this webpage come up https://www.google.com/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&tok=MgDrtaqTQMlSjz6LTciLag&cp=3&gs_id=d&xhr=t&q=mcdonalds&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=mcd&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=5f86932334452070&biw=1271&bih=885

Instead of this one: google.com

The google search query url looks quite complicated so I'd like to find a way to do pre-loaded search without having to touch the URL...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you should check to see if there is a google api or a rest api  that returns you that information. Then you can use restkit to get what you want.

Comment: I mean it shouldn't be a separate api though, right? This is the essence of google. I want to do a straight up google search, but just with a pre-rendered query

Comment: Actually using a google oriented api (a library for xcode) that can construct you what you want, I am not sure that it exists or it is obsolete though (or else I would have given you a definitive answer)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply use `https://www.google.com/search?q=YOUR_SEARCH_STRING`.

I think it's what you need

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple search engine:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=YOUR_SEARCH_STRING
https://www.bing.com/search?q=YOUR_SEARCH_STRING
https://www.search.yahoo.com/search?p=YOUR_SEARCH_STRING
```